# Editing a text file inside PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I made a Powershell script to update my mpv scripts. One of them being this
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpv-player/mpv/master/player/lua/osc.lua
I want the script to edit and remove all instances of `show_message(get_playlist(), 3)` from the file.

I tried `(get-content .\Scripts\osc.lua) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "show_message(get_playlist(), 3)", ""} | Out-File .\Scripts\osc.lua` and `(get-content .\portable_config\Scripts\osc.lua) | foreach-object {String.Replace [RegEx]::Escape('show_message(get_playlist(), 3)'),''} | Out-File .\portable_config\Scripts\osc.lua` but they dont seem to work.

Basically I want the script to automatically download osc.lua(which works fine as intended) and then remove all instances of `show_message(get_playlist(), 3)` from the file. My PowerShell version is 5.1.

Comment: Since `-replace` uses regex, you need to escape all regex special characters. You can replace `"show_message(get_playlist(), 3)"` with `[regex]::escape('show_message(get_playlist(), 3)')` in your code

Comment: @AdminOfThings That turns the file to 0 Kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following with the [Replace Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator):

```
$regex = [regex]::Escape('show_message(get_playlist(), 3)')
(Get-Content .\Scripts\osc.lua) -replace $regex |
    Set-Content .\Scripts\osc.lua
```

Alternatively, you can use the [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) method from the String class, which ***does not use regex***.

```
(Get-Content .\Scripts\osc.lua).Replace('show_message(get_playlist(), 3)','') |
    Set-Content .\Scripts\osc.lua
```

**Explanation:**

When using the `-replace` operator, the matching mechanism is a regex match. Certain characters are metacharacters for regex and must be escaped before they can be interpreted literally. In this case `(` and `)` need to be escaped. You can either do that manually with `\` (`\(` and `\)`) or use the `Escape()` method from the Regex class. From the code above, you can type `$regex` after its declaration and see how it was escaped.

When replacing a string with an empty string, you do not need to specify a replacement string. `'String' -replace 'ing'` has the same results as `'String' -replace 'ing',''`

---

**Note:** You are mixing `Get-Content` and `Out-File` in your code without using the `-Encoding` parameter. It is possible you could output a different encoding than the original file. If this matters to you, I'd suggest using the `-Encoding` parameter with the appropriate encoding.